# бесконечное движение фона

Tags: javascript

Уважаемые знатоки, нужно сделать на js горизонтальное движение фона (css не предлагать), думаю про такую реализацию

```
var count=0;
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("clouds").style.backgroundPosition='-'+ ++count+'px';
},100);
```

Вопрос: не принесет ли проблем бесконечный setInterval, например при достижении огромных значений в count, или лучше рекурсивно зациклить вращение фона (что бы после того, как картинка сделала полный круг, сбрасывался count и все начиналось сначала)

Благодарю за ответы, версии, полезные мысли.

Comment: на сколько большую картинку вы собираетесь так прокручивать?

Comment: with : 3000px;
height: 250px;

пардон, а размер имеет значение?)

Comment: ну вообще диапазон значений чисел в яваскрипте немного больше 3000

Comment: Движение будет рывками / неравномерно, т.к. JS неаккуратен в выполнении setTimeout. Почему таки не CSS3? Уточните, какие ещё ограничения вам нужно учитывать? Неплохая альтернатива, напр. CSS transform.

Comment: хм.. ну вы же понимаете что в текущей функции значение count не зависит от размера изображения, оно просто постоянно увеличивается.

Интересно реально ли вообще создать изображение шириной порядка квадрилиона пикселей...

Comment: ограничение на размер изображения – только в памяти устройства. Максимальное целое в JS = `2^53 – 1`

Comment: "Движение будет рывками / неравномерно, – Sergiks " решение работает, вполне хорошо, никакой разницы по сравнению с CSS animation я не увидел.
"Почему таки не CSS3?" - мне нужно сохранить позицию изображения при перезагрузке страницы
"какие ещё ограничения вам нужно учитывать" - других пока не выявлено, но в будущем могут появится
CSS transform - как и CSS animation  будет сброшен при перезагрузке страницы.

Comment: "ограничение на размер изображения – только в памяти устройства. Максимальное целое в JS = 2^53 "
это было небольшое лирическое отступление, и касалось оно процесса создания такого изображения, а не про его вывод на экран), но давайте по теме, если можно
и да 2в53 это и есть число порядка квадрилиона

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Абсолютно спозиционировать `<div>` с огромной картинкой. Двигать его, изменяя CSS-свойство не `background-position`, а `transform: translate(x, y)` – это «дешевая» операция без лишней [перерисовки](https://habrahabr.ru/post/224187/).

Для плавной анимации сделать её функцией от времени, через [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Чтобы после перезагрузки страницы вернуться к оставленному положению, назначить функцию, которая выполнится по событию [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) и запомнит текущее положение `<div>`'а в Cookie или [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage). При запуске, соотв., искать ранее сохранённое положение.

Answer (score 2):

Можно, как вариант, через css3 animation, решить вопрос

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://cg-evolution.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/red-brick-wall1.jpg");
  animation: scroll linear 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: да, можно было бы, если бы при перезагрузке страницы анимация не сбрасывалась на background-position: 0 0;

Comment: Не вижу в основном вопросе такого требования к бэкграунду, и как следствие не понимаю зачем что-то вообще сохранять в локальное хранилище или куки.
В конечном счете вопрос с помощью javscript можно было бы решить сотней разных способов.

Answer (score 2):

Тема до сих пор есть в поиске, поэтому добавлю сюда, может кому пригодится. Этот код работает без jQuery и не грузит комп пользователя.
Если нужно для тега body - замените .getElementById("ваш_id_элемента"). на .body. и разместите код перед /head.

JavaScript

```
`<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
window.setInterval(function () {
if (!this.a || this.a < 0) this.a = 300; //ширина img
else this.a--;
document.getElementById("ваш_id_элемента").style.backgroundPosition = this.a + "px 100px" //высота, можно в %%, если родительский элемент тоже в %
}, 110); //скорость
</script>`
```

CSS

```
`#ваш_id_элемента {
width: ...;
height: ...;
background: #000 url(http://.../sky.png) fixed;
}`
```

А есть и варианты на CSS. Если поэкспериментировать - можно добиться неплохих результатов:

[Анимация фона](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/animaciya-fona)

[Несколько фоновых картинок](https://webref.ru/layout/html5-css3/background/multiple)

[пример с воздушными шарами](http://jsfiddle.net/webref/u2mvx30g/)